# jQuery Add and Remove <li> class by Submit

Tags: jquery, css, tabs, html-lists, submit

I am gonna try to ask this question once again with a different approach.

This is my html:

```
<div class="tabs">
<ul class="tab-links">
    <li id="aa" class="active"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li id="bb"><a href="#CV">CV</a></li>
    <li id="cc"><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

The Contact tab contains a form, with a submit button.

This is the jQuery:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
  alert("Submitted");
  $('#aa').removeClass('active');
  $('#cc').addClass('active');
});
```

At this point, the jQuery only outputs the alert msg when the form submit button is pressed.
In addition I would like the < li > class = active, to be removed from the about < li > and be added to the contact < li >.

Comment: Please add your CSS for the `.active` class as well as the form HTML. A jsFiddle would be great.

Comment: Are you sure that the submit is not refreshing your page? Because if it does the elements would be back to initial state...

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong with this script. You're just missing the `.active` class styles.

## [CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/bbennett/pen/FecvH)

Keep everything as you have it, but add some CSS with the `active` class to show that the menu item is actually active.

**Sample CSS**

```
.active {
  background-color: red;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

You can do whatever you want, but you actually have to *tell* it what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to be adjusted so the page does not refresh -- the refresh resets everything to `page load` status. You can use `event.preventDefault()` and submit your form via ajax or else you'd have to use server-side code to manage the elements:

```
$("form").submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  //alert("Submitted");
  $('#aa').removeClass('active');
  $('#cc').addClass('active');
  //check #aa and #cc now
  //submit form via ajax here.
});
```